# my OnLoadRibbon subroutine isn't being called

Tags: excel, customization, vba

I'm just starting to use Microsoft UI Editor to customize ribbons in Excel. I'm trying to use the OnRibbonLoad subroutine to initilize editboxes and checkboxes with default values when the spreadsheet is opened. What I'm finding really strange is that I used the following code in a test spreadsheet and it worked fine:

```
Public MyRibbonUI As IRibbonUI

Private Sub OnRibbonLoad(ribbonUI As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbonUI = ribbonUI

    GBLDelimited = True
    MsgBox "Hello"
    'script to set global variable values to be used as default values
End Sub
```

But then when I use it in the spreadsheet I'm developing, it doesn't seem to be called at all. The  Msgbox line I added to test that the subroutine is getting called. In my test spreadsheet, the "Hello" message appears immediately after opening, suggesting that the subroutine is being called. However the message doesn't apear in my other spreadsheet.

I have a suspicion that this problem is directly related to my getting a "Runtime error 91" when I try to run this line in an onAction callback subroutine for a checkbox (trying to set a default value on opening):

```
MyRibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("checkBoxTest")
```

and I'm really sure the checkBox is correctly labeled.

Can anyone explain why the OnRibbonLoad subroutine works in one spreadsheet and not in another even though identical code is used?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem. In my Microsft UI Editor script for the second spreadsheet Im developing, I didn't include the OnLoad command

```
<customUI xmlns="......."    onLoad="OnRibbonLoad">
```

It was in my test spreadsheet but not in the one I'm developing. Feeling a bit silly now.